# How do I sync local folder to google compute engine instance folder?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am new to google cloud platform, just set up for first time.
My local machine is Windows 10. 
I have google cloud SDK installed.
I just set up a google compute engine instance.

How do I sync my local folder (with node js files etc) to the google compute engine instance folder?

I do not need this to be automated or scheduled. Doing this sync manually when I've made updates is adequate.

I read documentation online and tried the gsutil cp and rsync but it did not work. I'm not sure if these were the appropriate methods to use.

Thanks much.

Comment: If you are looking for an option just to transfer the files from your local workstation OS to Compute Engine instances, there are [several methods](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files) available. Using [WinSCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#winscp) is once such option. I hope this helps

Comment: I use both WinSCP and Bitvise on Windows for working with Linux instances. For Windows -> Windows you can use RDP and map a file share from your desktop to the Windows VM. Sometime next month I plan to release a program that integrates Compute Engine VMs into my development system with a large number of commands including directory syncs. I have already released a similar program for CloudShell on GitHub: https://github.com/jhanley-com/google-cloud-shell-cli-go

Comment: @Digil Thank you for the reference. I got it working with WinSCP.

Comment: @Necromon I am posting my suggestion as an answer so that other community members can take benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an option just to transfer the files from your local workstation OS to Compute Engine instances, there are several methods available which are explained in [**this help center article**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files).

Using [**WinSCP**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#winscp) is one such option for your use-case scenario.